# Pass to a case class constructor the instance being constructed

Tags: scala

I have a complex set of traits and case classes, but for the sake of the discussion let me summarize what I'm trying to model in this way:

```
case class X(x: X)
```

That's fine until I end up initializing one of the instances this way:

```
val myX: X = X(myX)
```

It compiles (unbelievably), but the `myX` passed to the constructor is actually *null*, easily visible by checking `myX.x` afterwards.

Suppose having an instance pointing to itself is fine for what I'm trying to model, is there an elegant way to solve this issue and have the new instance of `X` with a pointer to itself? I mean without mutating the object after its creation, nor introducing a 2nd constructor that takes no parameter and uses `this` inside. Remember please the real situation is more complex that what sketched here.

Comment: Maybe some trick with lazy vals and delayed evaluation of parameters ...

Comment: What exactly do you want to model? Because if it is an infinite data type, then it has to be lazy. If it is finite, then you need a way to signal the end, like an empty element. It may help check how **List** & **LayzList** are defined. As well as checking  the **Fix** concept of FP.

Comment: Wait, you said you want to pass to the constructor yourself? Why? That is not really possible and usually you shouldn't need it, you can use `this`.

Comment: I want to model objects that points to each other. For a valid reason, an object may point to itself. In case of immutable instances, how to initialize that instance?

Comment: If the pointers are always between only one or two objects and are bidirectional, I would suggest you consider moving the pointer part into another class which receives as parameters the chained objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to have a case class, I don't think it can be done. Case classes cannot have lazy parameters, and if they could point to themselves most of their methods would probably blow the stack. With a regular class you can do this:

```
scala> class X(x0: =>X) {
     |   lazy val x = x0 
     | }
class X

scala> val x: X = new X(x)
val x: X = X@5f98cb6f

scala> x.x
val res0: X = X@5f98cb6f

scala> x.x.x
val res1: X = X@5f98cb6f
```

If you want case class-like behavior you'll have to implement the boilerplate (apply, unapply, copy, equals, hashcode, ...) yourself, and be very careful not to trigger an infinite loop or a stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Ill-advisedly, consider "simulating" by-name parameters in case classes like so

```
case class X(v: () => X) {
  def x: X = v.apply
}

val myX: X = X(() => myX)
```

however note the warning by Jasper-M.

Comment: You can do that, but note that you'll lose most of the benefits of a case class because `X(() => myX) == X(() => myX)` will be false.